# Creating Graph object from CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which actually contains edge list like this:

```
"YDR143C","YER068W"
"YMR207C","YNR016C"
"YIL135C","YMR139W"
"YNL316C","YOL082W"
"YHR211W","YNL255C"
"YJL125C","YNL062C"
"YDL014W","YKL125W"
```

Now I need to create a graph from this and need to plot in Python. I m a new user of Python language and don't know how to read this file. How can I do this?

Comment: Search the matplotlib documentation. Your question is too broad.

Comment: I just need to know to read the files. I m facing the problem in reading the file. As the vertices are in double quotes it is not detecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is seemingly not about plotting, but about file reading. You can use the Python library [`csv_reader`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html)

```
import csv
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    mydata = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    for row in mydata:
        print(row)
```

Even more comfortable is the use of `pandas` that integrates the [`csv` reader among other I/O options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html):

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", names = ["x", "y"])
print(df)
```

How to plot these data is then a different question.